# How to execute a shell script using kubectl exec with arguments

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Hi I am having a shell script with name test.sh.It takes two arguments --a --b.I want to execute it using kubectl exec

I am currently following kubectl exec pod-name -- path-to-shell-file  ["Arguments"]

If i try it without the arguments the shell is working fine.

But this is not working.

Can you guys help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I think `kubectl exec pod-name -- shell-bin shell-script-path --a --b` should work. For example `kubectl exec pod-name -- /bin/bash /path_to/test.sh --a --b`. What is the error you are getting?

**EDIT**

Adding a working example

```
 ~ $ kubectl exec nginx-deployment-7c8f47687f-b5qmw -- cat /test.sh
echo The arguments for test.sh are $@

 ~ $ kubectl exec nginx-deployment-7c8f47687f-b5qmw -- /bin/bash /test.sh --a --b
The arguments for test.sh are --a --b
```

Comment: Hi Syam Sankar I am getting unknown argument error the --a argument is taken as a part of kubectl command.

Comment: @Sabarinathan I have added added a working example in the answer section as an edit. To answer what specifically happening to your case, can you please share the actual commands you are executing, the logs and the source code of the script.